# Torch getting stuck transfering model to GPU in multiple GPU setting

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gpu, pytorch

While using torch multiprocessing pool to paralelize the run of multiple equal experiences in multiple GPUs I ran into the fact that a lot of times the processes block in the transfer of the model from CPU to the assigned GPU. I don't understand the reason of the blocking.

I've tried manually deleting the model at the end of each run and collecting the not used GPU memory to no avail. I would like to understand why.

I'm running this on python 3.7 in a linux system with pytorch 1.2.0 and CUDA 10.0.130 with 4 NVIDIA 1080.

My main code is the following. VGG16 is just a big network. I can add the code of it too if you feel it's necessary.

```
import torch

from torch.multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Pool
from VGG16 import VGG16

def run_experiment(name, manager_dict, manager_lock):
    device_id = None
    manager_lock.acquire()
    for device_id in manager_dict.keys():
        if device_id == "n_processes":
            continue
        if manager_dict[device_id] < manager_dict["n_processes"]:
            manager_dict[device_id] += 1
            device_id = device_id
            break
    manager_lock.release()
    print(manager_dict, flush=True)
    device = torch.device(device_id)
    print(str(name)+ "selected device: " + str(device_id), flush=True)

    model = VGG16()
    print(str(name), "Initialized model", )
    model = model.to(device)
    print(str(name), "LOADED MODEL to the device")
    manager_dict[device_id] -= 1
    model_cpu = model.to(torch.device("cpu"))
    print(str(name), "Should have returned", flush=True)
    del model
    torch.cuda.ipc_collect()
    #return 1
    return model_cpu.state_dict()

def normal_experiments():
    n_processes_per_gpu = 2
    manager = Manager()
    manager_dict = manager.dict()
    manager_dict["n_processes"] = n_processes_per_gpu
    n_gpu = torch.cuda.device_count()
    print("Running on %d"%n_gpu, flush=True)
    for i in range(n_gpu):
        manager_dict[i] = 0
    manager_lock = manager.Lock()

    with Pool(processes=n_processes_per_gpu*n_gpu) as pool:
        #We call run experiment with seeds with its type of arguments
        iterable_arguments = [(str(i), manager_dict, manager_lock) for i in range(30)]
        res = pool.starmap(run_experiment, iterable_arguments)
    print("Done")

def main():
    torch.multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
    normal_experiments()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In this code some processes block in

```
model = model.to(device)
```

Comment: I remember dealing with this. Did you install the correct torch for the cuda version you are using? `conda install pytorch=1.2.0 torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`

Comment: Yes. I can do it again though and see if it fixes it. I think this is the only problem I've come across too.

Comment: Just did that. Also updated CUDA to 10.1 and same problem.